# Get a specific integer from text file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a question.
I am trying to grab a specific integer from a text file.

The text file is larger, but part of it contains this:

```
class="checkbox" name="reports[]" id="reports_43440"
```

Now, I am interested in the integer next to "reports_", which is different every time.

How do I get that specific integer from the text file?

I have tried this, but I couldn't get it work.

```
filereader = myFile.read()
reportid = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', filereader)
```

The problem is, that it returns everything within brackets from the text file. I would like to get only that specific integer though.

Comment: if this this the only purpose of your program, you can do the same with `grep` under Linux or ` Select-String` in PowerShell

Comment: this text file looks like HTML - if it is HTML maybe you should use HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

Let you have a text file called `test.txt` with following contents:

```
class="checkbox" name="reports[]" id="reports_12343440"
class="checkbox" name="reports[]" id="reports_4342340"
class="checkbox" name="reports[]" id="reports_4344430"
class="checkbox" name="reports[]" id="reports_4344130"
class="checkbox" name="reports[]" id="reports_434410"
class="checkbox" name="reports[]" id="reports_434403"
```

Now you can get the id value of reports_ using the regular expression like this:

```
import re
myFile = open("test.txt","r")
filereader = myFile.read()
regex = r"reports_([\d]+)"
reportid = re.findall(regex, filereader)
for id in reportid:
    print(id)
```

The output of the snippet is:

```
12343440
4342340
4344430
4344130
434410
434403
```

Here I have searched for matches with `reports_`. You can customize as much as you need.

Answer (score 0):

This code should fix your problem:

```
input = 'class="checkbox" name="reports[]" id="reports_43440"'

results = re.findall(r'"reports\_([^"]+?)"', input)
print results
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using [**re.search**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) function(if it should get a single integer value):

```
str = 'class="checkbox" name="reports[]" id="reports_43440"'
report_id = re.search(r'id="reports_(\d+)"', str).group(1)

print(report_id)
```

The output:

```
43440
```